# Expo app ComponentDidMount listener didFocus not triggering

Tags: react-native, expo, listener, event-listener

I have an expo app, this did work but has suddenly stopped - I'm not sure why as I have not updated anything on listsView.js.

When I delete a list in list.js the app returns to listsView.js as expected however the listener does not trigger and refresh the view (the list still remains on the screen).

Can anyone tell me when it is not triggering - I have tried moving it from componentDidMount to componentDidUpdate but that causes a loop when it loads until erroring.

My aim is for listsView.js to reload when navigating back to it to refresh the list of any deleted lists.

Here is the isolated code that is not triggering for listsView.js

```js
 componentDidMount() {
          console.log("didmount??")
          const { navigation } = this.props;
          this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
            console.log("refreshing list")  //this does not trigger
           this.getLists();
          });
        }
```

listsView.js

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TextInput, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';

 

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        loaded: true,
        error: null,
        token: "",
        modalVisible: false,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("didmount??")
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
        console.log("refreshing list")  //this does not trigger
       this.getLists();
      });
    }

    setModalVisible = (visible) => {
      this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }

    goToList(id, name){
      try{
      this.props.navigation.navigate('List', {  
        JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: id, listName: name 
    })
      console.log(id)
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    
baseURL = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth';

    showData = (data)=>{
        this.setState({loaded:true, data:data});    
    }

    badStuff = (err) => {
        this.setState({loaded: true, error: err.message});
    }
    
    getLists = () => {
    (async () => {
      const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
      // Your fetch code
      this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
      let url = this.baseURL + '/list';
      let h = new Headers();
      h.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');    
      let req = new Request(url, {
       headers: h,
       method: 'GET'
      });
      fetch(req)
      .then(response=>response.json())
      .then(this.showData)
     // .then(this.isMounted = true )
      .catch(this.badStuff)
   })();
  }

    componentDidMount() {
     this.getLists()
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={globalStyles.container}>
            
            <Modal visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
              <View style={globalStyles.container}>
                <MaterialIcons
                  name='close'
                  size={24}
                  color='orange'
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                  }}
                />
                <View style={globalStyles.centering}>
                  <View style={ globalStyles.logInScreen}>
                    <Text style={globalStyles.titleText}>Add New List</Text>
                      <Formik
                        initialValues={{ name: '' }}
                        onSubmit={values => {(async () => {
                          const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
                          this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
                          let url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth/addList';
                          let h = new Headers();
                            h.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
                            h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
                          let b = JSON.stringify({
                            name: values.name,
                          })
                          let req = new Request(url, {
                            headers: h,
                            body: b,
                            method: 'POST'
                          });
                          fetch(req)
                          .then(this.setModalVisible(false))
                          .then(this.getLists) 
                          .then(response=>response.json())
                          .catch(this.badStuff)
                        })();}}
                      >
                      {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                        <View>
                          <Text style={globalStyles.labelText}>Item:</Text>
                          <TextInput style={globalStyles.textInput}
                            onChangeText={handleChange('name')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('name')}
                            value={values.email}
                          />
                          <View style={globalStyles.buttons}>
                            <Button 
                              title='Add New List' 
                              onPress={handleSubmit}
                              color='orange'
                            />
                          </View>
                        </View>
                        )}
                      </Formik>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>



              { !this.state.loaded && (
                  <Text>LOADING</Text>
              )}
             
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20}}>
                <Ionicons 
                  name="md-add-circle"
                  size={31} color="orange" 
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 5, color: 'white'}}>Add List</Text>
              </View>
              
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={globalStyles.titleTextPadded}>Your Lists</Text>              
              </View>
              
              { this.state.error && (
                <Text >{this.state.error}</Text>
              )}
              
              <View style={globalStyles.listNamesView}>
                <FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 60}} 
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => this.goToList(item.lists.id, item.lists.name)}>
                      <Text style={globalStyles.listNameText}>
                        { item.lists.name }
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>                  
                  )}
                  keyExtractor = { (item) => item.lists.id.toString() }
                />  
              </View>  
        </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

list.js

```js
import React, { Component , useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TextInput, SafeAreaView, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';
import { CheckBox, Overlay } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import { MaterialIcons, Ionicons, Feather, AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native' // <-- import useNavigation hook



export default class App extends Component { 
   
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          loaded: true,
          error: null,
          modalVisible: false,
          userToken: "",
        };
    }

    showAlert = () => {
        Alert.alert(
          'DELETE',
          'Are you sure you want to delete this list? You will not be able to recover it!',
          [
            {text: 'Delete', onPress: () => this.deleteList(), style: 'destructive'},
            {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      }
      
    setModalVisible = (visible) => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
    }

    showData = (data)=>{
        this.setState({loaded:true, data:data});  
    }

    badStuff = (err) => {
        this.setState({loaded: true, error: err.message});
    }
    
    getItems = () => {
        (async () => {
            const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
            this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
            this.setState({userToken: token});
            let url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth/items';
            let h = new Headers();
            h.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
            let b = JSON.stringify({
                list_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item,
              }) 
            let req = new Request(url, {
                headers: h,
                body: b,
                method: 'POST'
            });
           return fetch(req)
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(this.showData)
            .catch(this.badStuff)       
        })();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._mounted = true;
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        this.getItems()
    }

    
    goToFriends = (id) => {
        try{
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Friends', {
                listID: id
            })
            console.log(id)
            } catch(error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          }

    updateStatus(itemID, itemStatus) {
        this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
        let token = this.state.userToken;
        let url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth/itemCheck';
        let h = new Headers();
        h.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
        let b = JSON.stringify({
            item_id: itemID,
            item_status: itemStatus,
            list_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item,
        })
        let req = new Request(url, {
            headers: h,
            body: b,
            method: 'POST'
        });
       return fetch(req)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(this.getItems) 
        .catch(this.badStuff)
    }

    clearChecked(itemID, itemStatus) {
        this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
        let token = this.state.userToken;
        let url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth/clearChecked';
        let h = new Headers();
        h.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
        let b = JSON.stringify({
            list_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item,
        })
        let req = new Request(url, {
            headers: h,
            body: b,
            method: 'POST'
        });
       return fetch(req)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(this.getItems) 
        .catch(this.badStuff)
    }

    deleteList(itemID, itemStatus) {
        console.log ('DELETE DELETE');
        this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
        let token = this.state.userToken;
        let url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/api/auth/deleteList';
        let h = new Headers();
        h.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
        let b = JSON.stringify({
            list_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item,
        })
        let req = new Request(url, {
            headers: h,
            body: b,
            method: 'POST'
        });
       return fetch(req)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(this.goToLists) 
        .catch(this.badStuff)
    }

    goToLists  = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ListsView');
      }


    render() {  
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={globalStyles.container}>   
                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
                    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
                        <MaterialIcons
                            name='close'
                            size={24}
                            color='orange'
                            onPress={() => {
                                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                            }}
                        />
                        <View style={globalStyles.centering}>
                            <View style={ globalStyles.logInScreen}>
                                <Text style={globalStyles.titleText}>Add Item</Text>
                                <Formik
                                initialValues={{ item: '' }}
                                onSubmit={values => {(async () => {
                                    const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
                                    this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
                                    let url = 'https://www.myWebsite.com/api/auth/addItem';
                                    let h = new Headers();
                                    h.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
                                    h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                                    h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');  
                                    let b = JSON.stringify({
                                        item: values.item,
                                        list_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item,
                                    })
                                    let req = new Request(url, {
                                        headers: h,
                                        body: b,
                                        method: 'POST'
                                    });
                                    fetch(req)
                                    .then(this.setModalVisible(false))
                                    .then(this.getItems) 
                                    .then(response=>response.json())
                                    .catch(this.badStuff)
                                })();}}
                                >
                                 {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                                    <View>
                                        <Text style={globalStyles.labelText}>Item:</Text>
                                        <TextInput style={globalStyles.textInput}
                                        onChangeText={handleChange('item')}
                                        onBlur={handleBlur('item')}
                                        value={values.email}
                                        />
                                        <View style={globalStyles.buttons}>
                                            <Button 
                                                title='Add Item' 
                                                onPress={handleSubmit}
                                                color='orange'
                                            />
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                 )}
                                </Formik>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>

            { !this.state.loaded && (
                <Text></Text>
            )}
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 10,}}>
                <Ionicons 
                  name="md-add-circle"
                  size={31} color="orange" 
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                  }}
                />
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 5, color: 'white'}}>Add Item</Text>
                
                <Feather
                    name="check-square"
                    size={31}
                    color="orange"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 20,}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.clearChecked();
                      }}
                />
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 5, color: 'white'}}>Clear</Text>
                
                <Ionicons 
                    name="ios-person-add"
                    size={31}
                    color="orange"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 20,}}
                    onPress={() => {
                       this.goToFriends(this.props.navigation.state.params.JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item);
                    }}
                />
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 5, color: 'white'}}>Friend</Text>
                
                <AntDesign 
                    name="delete"
                    size={31}
                    color="orange"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 20,}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.showAlert();
                    }}
                />
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingLeft: 5, color: 'white'}}>Delete</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Text style={ globalStyles.titleTextPadded}>{ this.props.navigation.state.params.listName}</Text>
            </View>
          
            { this.state.error && (
                <Text >{this.state.error}</Text>
            )}

            <View>
                <FlatList contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100}} 
                    data={this.state.data}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <CheckBox style={globalStyles.listItem}
                                title={ item.item }
                                checked = { Boolean(Number(item.status))}
                                value={this.state.checked}
                                onPress={() => this.updateStatus(item.id, item.status)}
                            /> 
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor = { (item) => item.id.toString() }
                />  
            </View>  
        </SafeAreaView>
        );
    } 
}
```

UPDATE:
I have not noticed my first mistake - I had 2 componentWillMount and the second was overriding the first.
I have now deleted the second and updated the first:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      console.log("didmount??")
      this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
        console.log("refreshing list")
       this.getLists();
      });
    }
```

This now works as expected when I delete a list and it returns to listsView.js however when I log in and listsView.js is first 'hit' it doest load the lists now!

Comment: are you unsubscribing your focusListener? also, is navigation correct if you console log it?

Comment: Hi @WenW thank you for your response. I have updated my question with more information. Initially, an obvious mistake that I made was duplicate componentWillMount however sorting that has now resulted in the lists not being loaded when the page is first hit

Comment: because you need to call the this.getLists() outside of your addListene.

Comment: @WenW I'm sure I did that and it still didn't work, however as is always the way - once someone tells me and I try it, it works perfectly! Thank you very much.